# Case-insensitive routes for web api 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Testing the below method in Fiddler is returning a 200 for **api/test** but a 301 for **api/Test**

I see there's a new option for MVC routes to enforce lowercase but can't find anything for web api routes.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("test")]
public IHttpActionResult Testing()
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36748072/47589 for why you shouldn't do this.

Comment: @Amy That selected answer states that SO does what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001455/should-a-rest-api-be-case-sensitive-or-non-case-sensitive) for a detailed answer.

Comment: @MortezaZabihi That link was already provided by Amy. While it's not "good practice" to do so, it's what we are trying to do to prevent calls to our help desk over a capital letter being in the URL. SO does this so it can't be that bad to do.

Answer (score -1):

By default, Web API looks for a case-insensitive match with the start of the controller method name.

Try to change your route for this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/test")]
public class TestController : ApiController

[HttpGet]
[Route("testing")]
public IHttpActionResult Testing()
{
   return Ok();
}
```

Your WebApiConfig.cs class must be with default settings:

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

For more informations about routing with webapi 2.0 look this page: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: Same result as with my example

Comment: Do you customized the WebApiConfig?

Comment: I did. The call to the method works fine but only when requested in all lowercase

Comment: I made some tests without any problem here, because of it I changed my post to show you how looks like my controller and my WebApiConfig I hope that may help you.