# ASP.NET can not find API controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, api

I'm currently working on a website that needs to fetch a string from an API controller, so that it can display it on the page as an image. Everything works fine when I run the site in Visual Studio, but when I publish it to the website itself, the server always responds with the following:

```
<Error>
<Message>No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://{website_name}/api/Files/GetProfilePicture?userId=cc6afd64-885e-4d8b-a239-42b161d665cc'.</Message>
<MessageDetail>No type was found that matches the controller named 'Files'.</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

Other Api controllers in the website are working perfectly fine, but it's specifically this controller that is being stubborn.

Here is the WebApiConfig.cs:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Here is the view:

```
@model {website_name}.Models.ProfilePictureGetModel

@{
    if (Model.userId == null)
    {
        Model.userId = Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions.GetUserId(User.Identity);
    }

    string style = "border-radius: " + Model.size + "px; height: " + Model.size + "px; width: " + Model.size + "px; object-fit: cover; cursor: pointer";
}

<body>
    <img class="pflPic @Model.userId" style="@style" onclick="location.href = '/Profile?id=' + '@Model.userId'" />
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/Files/GetProfilePicture",
            data: {
                id: '@Model.userId'
            },
            type: "GET",
            cache: true,
            async: true,
            success: function (result) {
                if (result) {
                    var pics = document.getElementsByClassName("@Model.userId")
                    for (var i = 0; i < pics.length; i++) {
                        if (pics[i].src == "")
                            pics[i].src = result;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
</script>
</body>
```

Here is the controller:

```
namespace {website_name}.Controllers.Api
{
    public class FilesController : ApiController
    {
        ApplicationDbContext _context;

        [HttpGet]
        [WebMethod]
        [ResponseType(typeof(String))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetProfilePicture(string userId)
        {
            var User = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == userId);

            if (User == null)
                return NotFound();

            string img = Convert.ToBase64String(User.ProfilePicture);
            if (User != null)
                return Ok("data:image;base64," + img);
            else
                return NotFound();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            _context.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        public FilesController()
        {
            _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to remove  [WebMethod]

Comment: I removed it, and it has no effect

Answer (score 1):

you can try classical MVC style url, and use full url if your webapi is not inside of your web application

```
var userId=$('#userId').val();

    $.ajax({
          url: "https://{website_name}/api/Files/GetProfilePicture/"+userId,
            type: "GET",
            success: function (result) {
          ......
```

and add this somewhere inside of the view form of your web application

```
<input id="userId" type="hidden" value="@Model.UserId">
```

it should send request to this url

```
https://{website_name}/api/Files/GetProfilePicture/cc6afd64-885e-4d8b-a239-42b161d665cc
```

action

```
[Route("~/api/Files/GetProfilePicture/{userId?}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetProfilePicture(string userId)
```

Comment: It still gave me the same 404 response. I think the issue might be that it can't find the controller, but I don't know why that'd be.

Comment: @Deathtraptaco What url do you see in 404 response?

Comment: https://{website_name}/api/Files/GetProfilePicture?userId=cc6afd64-885e-4d8b-a239-42b161d665cc

Comment: Did you use my ajax? You should have https://{website_name}/api/Files/GetProfilePicture/cc6afd64-885e-4d8b-a239-42b161d665cc url If you don't  want to follow the answers , you should never ask the questions here.

Comment: I added all the changes you suggested, and now it's redirecting to https://{website_name}/api/Files/GetProfilePicture/cc6afd64-885e-4d8b-a239-42b161d665cc?_=1632622493698. It gives me the default 404 page.

Comment: @Deathtraptaco Where   ? _=1632622493698 came  from? . Can you post the whole view code where are you calling the ajax. Do you click a button?

Comment: I added the view to my post. The  _=1632622493698 automatically was added to the request when it was made, after I changed the Route Config.

Comment: @Deathtraptaco Didi you check a {website_name} ? it should be API website, not your webapplication

Comment: {website_name} is just there to replace the domain name to protect the secrecy of the website.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with how your formatted the request url in your ajax call

```
   url: "/api/Files/GetProfilePicture/" + userId,
```

and it should be

```
   url: "/api/Files/GetProfilePicture?" + userId,
```

Comment: It still redirects me to the same response. I don't think that it's a problem with the action itself, but asp.net for some reason can't find the 'Files' controller.

Answer (score 0):

First - regarding the URL:

for starters - try reading this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection
seems like the you have 2 problems:

1. the parameter names are different:

   routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"

but the controller defines the parameter as "userId" which cant be found:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetProfilePicture(string userId)
```

They must match so youll have the change one of them:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetProfilePicture(string id)
```

2. The other thing is the uppercase issue. use lower cases as shown in the link above.

Secondly - the path is very unRESTful.
REST is about treating data as resources, so naming of url shoud contain resources exclusively.
You better avoid verbs, function names and CRUD actions (see: https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/).
Moreover - better use lowercase letters (see: [Should a REST API be case sensitive or non case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001455/should-a-rest-api-be-case-sensitive-or-non-case-sensitive))

An example for a better URL would be:

```
    [HttpGet("api/users/{userId}/files/profile-picture")]
```

Note that you would have to change the default routing as well.
Please try this and share the outcome.

Cheers!

Comment: I changed the parameter name, and it still gives me the same response

Comment: The thing is, everything works perfectly fine in visual studio, but when I upload the controller to Plesk to my site, It can't find the controller when I make requests to it.